# Convert message received from PubNub to Dictionary object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, pubnub

I have the following object C code for receiving PubNub message.

```
- (void)client:(PubNub *)client didReceiveMessage:(PNMessageResult *)message {


    NSLog(@"Received message: %@ on channel %@ at %@", message.data.message,
    message.data.subscribedChannel, message.data.timetoken);

}
```

The returned data is

```
Received message: (
    {
    key = userName;
    value = Enoch;
},
    {
    key = photoID;
    value = 3;
},
    {
    key = userID;
    value = 1;
},
    {
    key = actionType;
    value = chat;
},
    {
    key = message;
    value = H;
}
) on channel chat at 14888810882049989
```

I would like to parse the message to a dictionary object for accessing the "value" by using the "key"

I am very new in objective C programming and don't know how to do.

Please help.

Comment: where you called this `didReceiveMessage` in appdelegate or your VC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the message array and set the key value in dictionary.

```
NSArray *array = (NSArray*)message.data.message;
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *item in array) {
    [dic setObject:[item objectForKey:@"value"] forKey:[item objectForKey:@"key"]];
}
NSLog(@"%@", dic);
```

**Or**

```
NSArray *array = (NSArray*)message.data.message;
NSArray *values = [array valueForKey: @"value"];
NSArray *keys = [array valueForKey: @"key"];
NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
NSLog(@"%@", dic);
```

Comment: @EnochChan Welcome mate :)

Comment: its a array of dictionary `message.data.message`, then why you taken the another converson

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik OP want all the dictionary in single dictionary check the question once again mate. **"I would like to parse the message to a dictionary object for accessing the "value" by using the "key""**

Comment: @NiravD - ya but we can optimize , i think no need or fast enumration

Comment: @NiravD - we can do it another 2 ways, shall I modify your answer

Comment: @NiravD thanks you always makes Indian proud,  Mr. Doctorwala ?

Comment: @Rishi Welcome mate n Thanks for the compliment :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method for parsing your data and convert it into dictionary

```
ChatterBoxMessage *chatterBoxMessage = [[ChatterBoxMessage alloc] initFromDictionary: message.data.message  withTimeToken: message.data.timetoken];

[chatterBoxMessage asDictionary];
```

By This method you will get `dictionary`.

Above ChatterBoxMessage is a PubNub library class.

**Also you can parse your data like below :**

```
for (NSDictionary *objectData in message.data.message) {
      NSLog(@"Value : %@",objectData[@"value"]);
      NSLog(@"Key : %@",objectData[@"key"]);
}
```